# sharepoint 2013 workflow version

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I have downloaded and installed the trial version of Sharepoint 2013. I have also setup Sharepoint Designer because I want to see what workflows can do. Unfortunately, when I create a workflow, I can only select "Sharepoint 2010 Workflow" in the "Platform Type" dropdown. I also get this message, telling me that I cannot create a Sharepoint 2013 Workflow:

> "The option for the SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform is not available because the workflow service is not configured oon the server."

Everything runs on a single server - both the Sharepoint installation, the SQL server, the IIS server and the Designer thing.

Can anybody shed some light on this problem?

Regards Leif

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [sharepoint.se]

Answer (score 1):

There is a separate installation and setup that needs to be done in order to make SharePoint 2013 workflow type show up in the dropdown. You need to install workflow manager and link it to your farm and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

When working with SharePoint 2013, you must make sure you also have installed the 2013 SharePoint Designer (workflows) and 2013 InfoPath (designing forms) tools.  You can not use the 2010 tools with SharePoint 2013.